# Unable to run query in SQL Server Management Studio because of JIT debugging error

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, jit

Recently I have built a Windows Server 2008 and installed SQL Server 2008 and Dynamics CRM 2011 on it. Everything is working fine but when I open the SQL Server Management Studio and try to open a new query window, it throws the following error.

> When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
>   will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
>   rather than be handled by this dialog box.

**FULL ERROR MESSAGE**

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.'

************** Exception Text **************

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NewQueryMenuHandler.Invoke()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ToolsMenuItemBase.MenuInvokedHandler(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5477 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
AppIDPackage
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.4297.0 ((KJ_SP2_QFE-CU).131122-1719 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/AppIDPackage.DLL
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlTools.VSIntegration
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.4297.0 ((KJ_SP2_QFE-CU).131122-1719 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlTools.VSIntegration.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop
    Assembly Version: 7.1.40304.0
    Win32 Version: 7.10.6071
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop/7.1.40304.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop
    Assembly Version: 7.1.40304.0
    Win32 Version: 7.10.6070
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC/Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop/7.1.40304.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5468 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
SqlWorkbench.Interfaces
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1540 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/SqlWorkbench.Interfaces.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlTDiagM
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1539 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlTDiagM/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlTDiagM.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Instapi
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1540 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.Instapi/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.Instapi.dll
----------------------------------------
EnvDTE
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 8.0.50727.1826 (QFE.050727-1800)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC/EnvDTE/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/EnvDTE.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1826 (QFE.050727-1800)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 8.0.50727.1826 (QFE.050727-1800)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SDK.SqlStudio
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1540 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SDK.SqlStudio.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.DataWarehouse.SQM
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.4297.0 ((KJ_SP2_QFE-CU).131122-1719 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.DataWarehouse.SQM.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.4297.0 ((KJ_SP2_QFE-CU).131122-1719 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Controls
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1540 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Controls.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5476 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5476 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
ObjectExplorer
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.4297.0 ((KJ_SP2_QFE-CU).131122-1719 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/ObjectExplorer.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Design
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5468 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Design/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Design.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UserSettings
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.4297.0 ((KJ_SP2_QFE-CU).131122-1719 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UserSettings.DLL
----------------------------------------
SqlMgmt
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.4297.0 ((KJ_SP2_QFE-CU).131122-1719 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/SqlMgmt.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.2500.0 ((KJ_PCU_Main).110617-0038 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
----------------------------------------
ConnectionDlg
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.4297.0 ((KJ_SP2_QFE-CU).131122-1719 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/ConnectionDlg.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1826 built by: QFE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing.Design
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing.Design/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.Design.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Designer.Interfaces
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5000.0
    Win32 Version: 1.1.4322.573
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Designer.Interfaces/1.0.5000.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Designer.Interfaces.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.RegSvrEnum
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1539 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.RegSvrEnum/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.RegSvrEnum.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Reports
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.4297.0 ((KJ_SP2_QFE-CU).131122-1719 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Reports.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Migration
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1540 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Migration.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.2500.0 ((KJ_PCU_Main).110617-0038 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.NetEnterpriseServers.ExceptionMessageBox
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1539 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.NetEnterpriseServers.ExceptionMessageBox/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.NetEnterpriseServers.ExceptionMessageBox.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5459 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1540 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.DLL
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.2500.0 ((KJ_PCU_Main).110617-0038 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1539 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1539 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll
----------------------------------------
zirzmul5
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1539 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.2500.0 ((KJ_PCU_Main).110617-0038 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClient
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1539 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClient/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClient.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2009.0100.1600.01 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1540 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll
----------------------------------------
msvcm80
    Assembly Version: 8.0.50727.4940
    Win32 Version: 8.00.50727.4940
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/WinSxS/x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_d08cc06a442b34fc/msvcm80.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.4297.0 ((KJ_SP2_QFE-CU).131122-1714 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.PolicyEnum
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1539 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.PolicyEnum/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.PolicyEnum.dll
----------------------------------------
ObjectExplorerReplication
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1540 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/ObjectExplorerReplication.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Sqm
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1540 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.SqlServer.Sqm.DLL
----------------------------------------
kqkecfyx
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
SQLEditors
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.4297.0 ((KJ_SP2_QFE-CU).131122-1719 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/SQLEditors.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Scripting
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.1600.1 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1540 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Scripting.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.4297.0 ((KJ_SP2_QFE-CU).131122-1719 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.5420 built by: Win7SP1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DacEnum
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.50.4297.0 ((KJ_SP2_QFE-CU).131122-1719 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DacEnum/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DacEnum.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop
    Assembly Version: 7.1.40304.0
    Win32 Version: 7.10.6070
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop/7.1.40304.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: It looks like SSMS isn't properly installed. I'd try to re-install it.

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem. Can you convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and I found that .Net 3.5 needed to be installed/enabled on my Server 2008. This resolved the issue and did not require a reboot.

**How to install/enable .Net 3.5 SP1 on Windows Server 2008 R2 for SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2**

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlblog/2010/01/08/how-to-installenable-net-3-5-sp1-on-windows-server-2008-r2-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2/